# Ubuntu 22.04 Third Level Characters not available US Keyboard

Tags: 22.04, dell, keyboard-layout, character-set

i have a DELL XPS 13 7390 Notebook and run Ubuntu 22.04.02.
My problem is i can't reach third level characters from my keyboard. I don't need these symbols very much but enough that it annoys me.

After going to the regular settings and set the 'Alternate Characters Key' to 'Right Alt' nothing chatnges. Also i have tried the Tweaks settings and went to the 'Additional Layout Options', where i set the 'Alt Right' key to enter the third Level characters. Still nothing happen. ChatGPT told me to reconfigure my keyboard in the BIOS with 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration'.
Well also didnt work.

Anyone having a idea what to try next? Also i have tried to contact Dell on this issue. But don't expect them to be able to help.

Thanks very much for your time

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Right, Alt_R on Dell Laptop keyboards doesn't work as expected. You can set another modifier on Alt_R and then change it to `AltGr` `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` . Or you can use `compose` key to print many symbols.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show us the output of these terminal commands: 1. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` 2. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`